# Import Angular directive in Ionic 3 in app.module.js

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to add an [npm package](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue)  that automatically scrolls to the bottom of an element in ionic 3. I keep getting an error after I import:

**ERROR**

> scrollglue.js:164 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

**app.module.js**

```
    import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    //trying to import this angular directive 
    import { GlueScroll } from 'angularjs-scroll-glue';


    ....

  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    PaymentPage,
    PaypalPage,
    AboutPage,
    GlueScroll
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,  {
        tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
    }),
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
        showTitle: false,
        showSubtitle: false,
        showUnits: false,
        space: -6,
        backgroundPadding: -4,
        backgroundStrokeWidth : -3
    }),
    PipesModule
  ],
```

**Plunker**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/wxTyp7PpyxJOHSlUumVC?p=preview

Comment: which version of angular?

Comment: it is version 2.1.0